# Maximise x+y, where the integer coord (x,y) lies within an ellipse

Tags: geometry

Given the equation for an ellipse $\frac{\left(x-a\right)^{2}}{c^{2}}+\frac{\left(y-b\right)^{2}}{d^{2}}=k.$
Find the maximum value of $x+y$ where integers $x$ and $y$ are such that such that the coordinate $(x,y)$ lies within or on the ellipse. (Note that there might be multiple points that satisfy this requirement).
E.g. for $\frac{\left(x-1\right)^{2}}{9}+\frac{\left(y-2\right)^{2}}{16}=1$, we have points $(1, 6), (2, 5)$ and $(3, 4)$ all of whom have the sum $x+y=7$ which is the maximum.
[image: Diagram for example]

My current theory is that if we take the point of tangency for $y=-x+e$ and the ellipse's upper right quadrant, we can find the max value of $x+y$ for a non-integer coordinate on the the ellipse. Then the point $\left(\lfloor x \rfloor, \lfloor y \rfloor \right)$, to find the closest integer point within the ellipse. However using this method, there may be some nasty edge cases in which the floor function may not work. (in the attachment we see that for $y=-x+8$ the flooring method does work since $\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor = 7$. which is the maximum) I am unsure how to prove or disprove this, or if there even exists an expression that in terms of $a, b, c, d$ and $k$.
[image: Graph with y=-x+8]

Comment: Your example actually shows that the flooring method *doesn't* work in general, since $\lfloor 8\rfloor = 8$. Or else you could move it up/to the right by $\varepsilon$ if you don't like the case of equality.

Comment: I see i think I will clarify that, what i meant was taking that position and using the point floor x, and floor y since that will always be within the bounds of the ellipse, therefore floor(2.8)+floor(5.2) = 7 which does work. I will make an edit to make this more clear.

Comment: What was the reasoning for the selection of the tangent point?

Comment: Your method does not work. For the ellipse $\dfrac{x^2}{2^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{1^2}=1$, considering the tangent line $y=-x+\sqrt 5$ gives $\left\lfloor\dfrac 4{\sqrt 5}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 5}\right\rfloor=1$ which is smaller than $2+0=2$.

Comment: Yea I see, I guess there may be another solution that works, that was just my hypothesis. I'm not sure how to continue from here tho.